# Why passing an argument of structure pointer in a function which creates link list node isn't working?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to make link list which represents polynomial.
Each node consists of coefficient,power of x,link to the next node
I have tried this program without passing arguments it worked .
but when when tried passing arguments the link list isn't being created.
pls help to rectify my program..

*****THIS IS MY PROGRAM WITH STRUCTURE POINTERS AS AN 
ARGUMENT IN THE INSERT FUNCTION*****

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
float coff;
int expo;
struct node *next;
};

struct node *start1=NULL,*current1=NULL;

void insert(struct node *start,struct node *current)
{
struct node *new_node;

new_node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

if(start==NULL)
{
    start=new_node;
    current=new_node;
}
else
{
    current->next=new_node;
    current=new_node;
}

printf("\nEnter coefficient:");
scanf("%f",&new_node->coff);
printf("\nEnter power of x:");
scanf("%d",&new_node->expo);
new_node->next=NULL;
}
void show(struct node *start)
{
struct node *ptr;
ptr=start;

    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf(" %.2fx^%d",ptr->coff,ptr->expo);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
void find(float scoff,int sexpo,struct node *start)
{
//scoff=search coefficient, sexpo=search exponent
int flag=0;
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr=start;

    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        if(ptr->coff==scoff && ptr->expo==sexpo)
        {
          printf("your term found-> %.1fx^%d",ptr->coff,ptr->expo);
          flag=1;
          break;
        }
        else
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }

    if(flag==0)
        printf("\nSorry term couldn't be found!!");
    else
        printf("\nSearch success!!");

 }
 int main()
 {
 int c=1,ex=0;
 float cf=0;
 while(1)
 {
    insert(start1,current1);
    printf("\nWant to continue(1/0)?");
    scanf("%d",&c);
        if(c==0)
            break;
 }
 show(start1);
 while(1)
 {
    printf("\nEnter coff and expo respectively:");
    scanf("%f%d",&cf,&ex);
    find(cf,ex,start1);

    printf("\nWant to continue(1/0)?");
    scanf("%d",&c);
        if(c==0)
            break;
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're modifying a local copy of the start and current pointers (i.e. the copies passed as the function arguments), thus not actually changing the linked list. You should instead modify the `start1` and `current1` pointers. There's no need for the insertion function to take `start` and `current` parameters as it can simply modify the global variables. (I should note that this is a bad design choice.)

More specifically, the problem is when initializing the list in

```
if (start==NULL)
{
    start=new_node;
    current=new_node;
}
```

you only modify the local copy that gets destroyed when it goes out of scope. So `start1` and `current1` are still `NULL` after the function returns.

Change the insert function to

```
void insert(struct node *start,struct node *current)
{
struct node *new_node;

new_node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

if(start1==NULL)
{
    start1=new_node; // You previously  had start instead of start1
    current1=new_node; // You previously had current instead of current1
}
else
{
    current1->next=new_node;
    current1=new_node;
}

printf("\nEnter coefficient:");
scanf("%f",&new_node->coff);
printf("\nEnter power of x:");
scanf("%d",&new_node->expo);
new_node->next=NULL;
}
```

Beware: after this modification, you can call `insert()` (i.e. no need for `insert` to have parameters) as the function will operate on the global variables. The other option---better, but more time-consuming---is to somehow initialize the linked list and then use the functions in their current form (except for minor modifications).